# web.config error from a blank published .net core project

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to publish to my local IIS. I'm publishing to a folder and set up a new website in IIS and set the the path to my published folder.
I get HTTP Error 500.19 the path is specified as such:  \?\S:\Source....
Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:

I've tried every solution I can find on net and given IIS_IUSRS permission to the folder. Even if I create an empty api solution .net core I get this error.

Comment: Have you ever [Installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)?

Comment: this is correct.. If you add as answer I will mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have [installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle).